# interactive jvm 11 commands / CRaSH for java 11

Tags: java, shell, crash

I am searching for a solution where one can get some kind of a shell in a running jvm and do some monitoring and provide custom commands.

Found http://www.crashub.org a few years ago and it was running via Spring boot, it got more or less replace with that actuator thing I guess. 
But with no support to have a shell like experience.

**So is there any CRaSH like replacement for java 11, maybe some crude simple hack with jshell?**

Some more Background:
I want to define a command where one can execute arbitrary mvel expressions or similar to actually change objects in a database using business logic.

And yes ... this could be security wise ... a big mess.

Comment: Why doesn't it work on Java 11?

Comment: @jbx half of the command don't work because of the new module structure introduced by java 9, also groovy embedded parts don't seem to play that well with the new world as well